# Runtime error when casting from FARPROC to function pointer with varargs

Tags: c, casting, dll-injection

I'm working on an old program that doesn't save or load its files anymore. While looking around in a DLL for a place to start, I noticed that there is some logging functionality that is disabled by default but should still work. Using a proxy DLL, I managed to activate logging by calling the right functions from the real DLL. However, I got stuck at using the actual logging functions, as the program crashes with Error `0xc0000142` whenever I get close to using them. All binaries involved are 32 bit.

Here's what I'm doing in my proxy DLL:

```
// undname ?ForceDebugLog@@YAXXZ = void __cdecl ForceDebugLog(void)
typedef void (*FDLAddr_t)(void);
FDLAddr_t ForceDebugLog;

// undname ?LogInfo@@YAXPBDZZ = void __cdecl LogInfo(char const *,...)
typedef void (*LIAddr_t)(char const *, ...);
LIAddr_t LogInfo;

// called on DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH
void setupFuncs() {
    HMODULE trueDll= GetModuleHandleA(".\\realDll.dll");
    ForceDebugLog = (FDLAddr_t)GetProcAddress(realDll, "?ForceDebugLog@@YAXXZ");

    // LogInfo = (LIAddr_t)GetProcAddress(realDll, "?LogInfo@@YAXPBDZZ");
}
```

Now, I can just do `ForceDebugLog()` and logging gets enabled. However, as soon as I uncomment the `LogInfo` line, the program crashes on startup with Windows showing the error `0xc0000142`.

Further experimentation shows that `GetProcAddress` returns the address of `LogInfo` in the DLL, i.e. this is working correctly. Also, everything works if `LogInfo` was a `FARPROC`. As soon as I add the cast to `LIAddr_t`, the error comes back.

How can I work around this issue? Do I need to take a different approach for functions with varargs? If this is a problem that has to be solved using C++ constructs, that's fine too.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and remove the wrong language tag. Also, provide the full output your code produces.

Comment: Make sure you are using the `__cdecl` calling convention https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-170 , as the link says check the compiler flags to see if the default has been changed.  Also `HMODULE trueDll= GetModuleHandleA(".\\realDll.dll");` looks wrong (as the code below uses `realDll`), and make sure to check all return results.

Comment: C0000142 means DLL initialization failed.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Both tags are vaild, as the original program was (probably) written in C++ and I'm writing C as I'm more comfortable with it. Added info in edit.

Comment: @user207421 I didn't think it was relevant to include that in the question. Added in edit.

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for the waste of everyone's time.

While looking at my DLL in ghidra, I noticed that there were some strings defined that appeared nowhere in my code. As it turns out, some old object files from earlier experiments were accidentally linked into the DLL. One of the experiments was a reimplementation of `LogInfo` which caused the compiler/linker to produce an incorrect result without throwing an error or warning (unless /wd5045 suppresses it, which I highly doubt).

This has the side effect that I now have to rework my makefile. Oh joy.